# Json not serializable in Python

Tags: python, json, serialization

I have a list of objects in this format as below. I wanted to save it in a json file format.

```
{'result': [{'topleft': {'y': 103, 'x': 187}, 'confidence': 0.833129, 'bottomright': {'y': 375, 'x': 271}, 'label': 'person'}]}
```

I was able to print the objects as above. But, when I try to save it in JSON format. I encounter error "raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")"

Here's part of my code:

```
def writeToJSONFile(data):
    filePathNameWExt = '/media/test/abc.json'
    with open(filePathNameWExt, 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(data, fp)

result = tfnet.return_predict(img)
data['result']=result
print (data)   
writeToJSONFile(data)
```

Comment: when i set result to the json string you post above, I can execute the script properly, what is tfnet.return_predict(img) return

Comment: it returns `[{'topleft': {'y': 103, 'x': 187}, 'confidence': 0.833129, 'bottomright': {'y': 375, 'x': 271}, 'label': 'person'}]`

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that the type you are using for floating points is not JSON serializable. If you don't want to got through the hassle of [making it serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable), you can simply convert it to "regular" floats before serializing.

For example, if you are using numpy floats (numpy.floating), you could do something like this:

```
result = tfnet.return_predict(img)

# Hack: Convert any numpy floats in result to regular floats.
# The lambda takes a (key,value) tuple and returns (key, float(value)), for any
# values that are numpy floats, without modifiying other values.
# The map applies the lambda to all (key,value) tuples in result.items().
serializable_result = dict(map(lambda (k, v): (k, float(v) if isinstance(v, numpy.floating) else v), result.items()))

data['result']=serializable_result 
print (data)   
writeToJSONFile(data)
```

The precise code above might not work for your specific objects, but the general idea is simply to convert any non "standard" floats to standard serializable floats before serializing.